# Creating SQLite database in intellij

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, intellij-idea

I have to create a SQLite database that I will ultimately have to insert lines of data from a parsed .csv file. The issue that I'm having is creating the SQLite database in the intellij idea. Using the code below I continue to get the "No suitable driver" error.  I believe that I've added the classpath correctly by using Project Structure-> Modules-> Add then selecting my downloaded SQLite .jar file, which in this case is sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1 (1).jar

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class mint {

    public static void createNewDatabase(String fileName) {

        String url = "C:\\SQLite\\sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1 (1).jar" + fileName;

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("A new database has been created.");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("An error occurred while connecting MySQL database");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createNewDatabase("input-filename.db");

    }
}
```

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKuQC.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [this tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/create-database/) - URL should be like this

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/" + fileName;
```